# Cómo comparar dos campos de tipo DataTime en MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Alguien puede resolver mi duda: tengo una base de datos de una maquina que hace Lotes de diferentes Productos en diferentes maquinas (reactores) y los productos pasan por un número determinado de procesos ejemplo (un total de 11 etapas) y de cada etapa se registra en fecha y hora (con un campo datatime)cuando empieza y termina(ejm- producto x01 reactor 2 etapa 1 Horainicio el 05/04/2018 11:44:37 HoraFinal 13:12:07

como puedo hacer que se obtengan las horas totales producidas por cada lote, es decir, de cuando inicio en etapa 1 a cuando finalizo en etapa 11

Hice esta consulta para traer todos los lotes terminados:

```
$consulta ="SELECT DISTINCT* FROM lote where Etapa=11
```

pero hice una igual para los lotes que inician , pero no se como hacer la comparación con los lotes correspondientes ya que como decía se crea info por cada etapa[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
time_to_sec(
  timediff( 
    MIN( HoraIncio ), MAX( HoraFinal ) 
    )
) / 3600 

FROM lote WHERE Lote = 'TBF-205';
```

La instrucción parafraseada sería:

Selecciona la fecha más antigua de HoraInicio, la más reciente de HoraFinal, sacas la diferencia y lo casteas a segundos, el resultado entre 3600 ( segundos en una hora ) de la tabla de lotes donde lote sea igual a 'TBF-205'

Comment: disculpa cres que aya alguna manera donde  no tenga que poner el lote espesifico es decir que  aga la comparacion para  todos los lotes  ??

Comment: Considero que con un group by lote, inténtalo, si no funciona abre un nuevo hilo con la nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias primero calcular los intervalos entre cada etapa, luego sumarlos

```
<?php
$fechainicio = new DateTime('tablas->HoraInicio');
$fechafin = new DateTime('tablas->HoraFin');

$intervalo = $fechainicio ->diff($fechafin);

$horas=$intervalo->format('%H');//horas
$minutos=$intervalo->format('%i');//Minutos
?>
```

Luego sumas todos de la etapa en un bucle de acuerdo al atributo "NumOrden"